# SQL: How to do conditional UPDATES

Tags: sql-server, sql-server-2008

Sorry, the title is not so great, to say the least.

In my CUSTOMER table I have 4 columns for phone numbers: P1, P2, P3, P4.
And I also have 1 column that tells me if there are no phone numbers at all: NOPHONE with a value of 1 or 0 (I know it sounds foolish, but it's a long story, so that's the way it is.)

Whenever I don't have a phone number, the value is 1 (it also has its reason).

Now, what I have to do, is UPDATE all the phone numbers that have a 0, and change the value to NULL... with the exception of those records that have NOPHONE=1 (and will have P1=P2=P3=P4=0), which should remain as they are (that is, 0).

How can I do that in 1 SQL statement?

Thanks!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
UPDATE Customer
SET P1 = NULLIF(P1, 0), P2 = NULLIF(P2, 0), P3 = NULLIF(P3, 0), P4 = NULLIF(P4, 0)
WHERE NOPHONE = 0
```

Answer (score 3):

Use a `CASE` statement to conditionally set the value. If you want to keep the current value, just set it to itself. The `WHERE` clause checks that at least one column will need to be changed.

```
UPDATE CUSTOMER
SET
  P1 = CASE WHEN P1 = 0 THEN NULL ELSE P1 END,
  P2 = CASE WHEN P2 = 0 THEN NULL ELSE P2 END,
  P3 = CASE WHEN P3 = 0 THEN NULL ELSE P3 END,
  P4 = CASE WHEN P4 = 0 THEN NULL ELSE P4 END
WHERE NOPHONE = 0
  AND (P1 = 0 OR P2 = 0 OR P3 = 0 OR P4 = 0)
```

Your `NOPHONE` logic seems backwards.  Intuitively I'd expect `NOPHONE = 1` to indicate that no phone numbers are available but your question is worded exactly the other way.

Comment: I think you need to add this condition asw ell and NOPHONE!=1

Comment: @Yuck - it was a typo, the next parragraph had it right. Anyhow, I corrected it. Which means you statement should say WHERE NOPHONE=0, right? Thanks.